# Premake5 isnt building to the correct directory

Tags: premake

Every time I compile my premake5 project it compiles to `Build/bin/` even though in the code it says `targetdir "Build/bin/%{cfg.buildconfig}/"` and this isn't only happening on Linux it also happens on windows. I believe it happens when premake5 parses my script since in the makefile it says `TARGETDIR = Build/bin` also this only happens with `targetdir` and `objdir` works as expexted.

‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it should be `%{cfg.buildcfg}` not `%{cfg.buildconfig}`, i.e:

```
targetdir "Build/bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}/"
```

See [Tokens list](https://premake.github.io/docs/Tokens/)